# Emacs org-mode - weekly journal carryover

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I recently switched my org journal from `daily to `weekly. I have `org-journal-carryover-items` set to `TODO=\"TODO\"`.

Since making this change, I no longer have TODOs carried over from one day to the next. Is this expected behaviour, and if so, how can I get carryover to work again without switching back to `daily?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not intended and it does work for me. Please file an issue at https://github.com/bastibe/org-journal with a reproducible example.